# Why am I getting an ArrayIndexOutOfBounds error in my code? I do not set a default length to my ArrayAdapter

Tags: android, sharedpreferences, spinner, settings

I'm creating my own Settings activity, and so far I have set one user option. It
is a spinner, and when the user changed the spinner value, the value will be saved to SharedPreferences. This will affect something in a different area of my app.

The idea is that whenever the user opens the Settings activity, it will read from SharedPreferences and set the selection to the value last selected by the user.

However, I am getting an "ArrayIndexOutOfBounds exception: length = 4" at the end of my onCreate() method. The logcat does not show any specific reason why this is happening. This is my first time using a Spinner and ArrayAdapter, so maybe I'm missing something, but I do not set a length for my ArrayAdapter, and the array that I pass it has a length of 4.

I'm thinking the crash might have something to do with the SharedPreferences aspect of thing, but I can't think of why. I also need to know how to stop the onItemSelected() method from firing without any user interaction.

Here is the code:

```
package groovinchip.com.callmanager;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener;

public class Settings extends AppCompatActivity implements OnItemSelectedListener{

    SharedPreferences appPrefs;
    public final String APP_PREFS = "appPrefs";
    private boolean isChecked = false;
    Spinner chatPicker;
    String infoMsg;
    int chatSelection; // for saving
    int currentChat; // for displaying

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setAppTheme();
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_settings);
        openAppPrefs();
        setChatSpinner();
    }

    // Set the app theme based on boolean value from
    // SharedPreferences
    private void setAppTheme() {
        openAppPrefs();
        Boolean isDark = appPrefs.getBoolean("themeVal", false);
        if(isDark==true){
            setTheme(R.style.AppThemeDark);
            isChecked = true;
        }
        else{
            setTheme(R.style.AppTheme);
            isChecked = false;
        }
    }

    public void openAppPrefs(){
        appPrefs = this.getSharedPreferences(APP_PREFS, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    }

    // Instantiate the 'custom chat' spinner;
    // Get the specified value from SharedPreferences
    // Based on the value retrieved, set the spinner choice
    public void setChatSpinner(){
        chatPicker = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.chatPicker);
        ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this,
                R.array.custom_chats, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
        adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        chatPicker.setAdapter(adapter);
        chatPicker.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);

        currentChat = appPrefs.getInt("chatSelectionID", 0);
        switch (currentChat){
            case 0:
                chatPicker.setSelection(R.string.CA_optional_chat_default);
                break;
            case 1:
                chatPicker.setSelection(R.string.CA_optional_chat_whatsapp);
                break;
            case 2:
                chatPicker.setSelection(R.string.CA_optional_chat_telegram);
                break;
            case 3:
                chatPicker.setSelection(R.string.CA_optional_chat_facebook_messenger);
                break;
            default:
                chatPicker.setSelection(R.string.CA_optional_chat_default);
                break;
        }
    }

    // Do something when a spinner item is chosen
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int pos, long id){
        switch (pos){
            case 0:
                infoMsg = "SMS option chosen";
                createUserInfoMessage(infoMsg);
                saveChatChange(pos);
                break;
            case 1:
                infoMsg = "WhatsApp option chosen";
                createUserInfoMessage(infoMsg);
                saveChatChange(chatSelection);
                break;
            case 2:
                infoMsg = "Telegram option chosen";
                createUserInfoMessage(infoMsg);
                saveChatChange(chatSelection);
                break;
            case 3:
                infoMsg = "Facebook Messenger option chosen";
                createUserInfoMessage(infoMsg);
                saveChatChange(chatSelection);
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
    }

    // Create a toast message to the user to show which settings option they have chosen
    public void createUserInfoMessage(String message){
        Toast toast = Toast.makeText(this, message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
        toast.show();
    }

    // Save user selection to SharedPreferences
    public void saveChatChange(int position){
        chatSelection = position;
        openAppPrefs();
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = appPrefs.edit();
        editor.putInt("chatSelectionID", chatSelection);
        editor.commit();
    }

    // Required
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent){
        // Do nothing
    }
}
```

EDIT: Below is the stack trace

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                 Process: groovinchip.com.callmanager, PID: 6702
                                                 java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=4; index=2131623943
                                                     at java.util.Arrays$ArrayList.get(Arrays.java:3769)
                                                     at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.getItem(ArrayAdapter.java:385)
                                                     at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.createViewFromResource(ArrayAdapter.java:441)
                                                     at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.getView(ArrayAdapter.java:407)
                                                     at android.widget.Spinner.makeView(Spinner.java:712)
                                                     at android.widget.Spinner.layout(Spinner.java:660)
                                                     at android.widget.Spinner.onLayout(Spinner.java:622)
                                                     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:19590)
                                                     at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6053)
                                                     at android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout.onLayout(ConstraintLayout.java:1197)
                                                     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:19590)
                                                     at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6053)
                                                     at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:323)
                                                     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:261)
                                                     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:19590)
                                                     at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6053)
                                                     at android.support.v7.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout.onLayout(ActionBarOverlayLayout.java:443)
                                                     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:19590)
                                                     at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6053)
                                                     at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:323)
                                                     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:261)
                                                     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:19590)
                                                     at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6053)
                                                     at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1791)
                                                     at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1635)
                                                     at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1544)
                                                     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:19590)
                                                     at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6053)
                                                     at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:323)
                                                     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:261)
                                                     at com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.onLayout(DecorView.java:758)
                                                     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:19590)
                                                     at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6053)
                                                     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performLayout(ViewRootImpl.java:2484)
                                                     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:2200)
                                                     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1386)
                                                     at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:6733)
                                                     at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:911)
                                                     at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:723)
                                                     at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:658)
                                                     at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:897)
                                                     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:789)
                                                     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:98)
                                                     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6541)
                                                     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                     at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240)
                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:767)
```

Comment: Can you post a full stack trace?

Comment: I edited the OP with the stack trace for you

Answer (score 0):

Your code includes this switch statement:

> ```
> currentChat = appPrefs.getInt("chatSelectionID", 0);
> switch (currentChat){
>     case 0:
>         chatPicker.setSelection(R.string.CA_optional_chat_default);
>         break;
>     case 1:
>         chatPicker.setSelection(R.string.CA_optional_chat_whatsapp);
>         break;
>     case 2:
>         chatPicker.setSelection(R.string.CA_optional_chat_telegram);
>         break;
>     case 3:
>         chatPicker.setSelection(R.string.CA_optional_chat_facebook_messenger);
>         break;
>     default:
>         chatPicker.setSelection(R.string.CA_optional_chat_default);
>         break;
> }
> ```

The `setSelection()` method takes in a *position* argument, but you are passing it a *resource identifier* instead. If you open your `R.string` class, you'll see each of these constants defined, and they will have values that are much larger than 0-3 (or potentially values that are negative). Here's an example from one of my projects:

```
public static final class string {
    ...
    public static final int ANYTIME=0x7f110072;
    ...
}
```

It turns out you can simplify your code drastically, considering that `currentChat` is itself a position. Try this:

```
currentChat = appPrefs.getInt("chatSelectionID", 0);
chatPicker.setSelection(currentChat);
```

### Update

To stop the item selection listener from firing without user interaction, move this line:

```
chatPicker.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
```

below the code where you call `chatPicker.setSelection()`. Calling `setSelection()` will trigger your listener.

The reason the selected position isn't being saved if you change the selection, leave the activity, and then return is due to this code:

> ```
> public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int pos, long id){
>     switch (pos){
>         case 0:
>             infoMsg = "SMS option chosen";
>             createUserInfoMessage(infoMsg);
>             saveChatChange(pos);
>             break;
>         case 1:
>             infoMsg = "WhatsApp option chosen";
>             createUserInfoMessage(infoMsg);
>             saveChatChange(chatSelection);
>             break;
>         case 2:
>             infoMsg = "Telegram option chosen";
>             createUserInfoMessage(infoMsg);
>             saveChatChange(chatSelection);
>             break;
>         case 3:
>             infoMsg = "Facebook Messenger option chosen";
>             createUserInfoMessage(infoMsg);
>             saveChatChange(chatSelection);
>             break;
>         default:
>             break;
>     }
> }
> ```

In every `case` other than `0`, you're saving `chatSelection` instead of `pos`. You could simplify to this:

```
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int pos, long id){
    switch (pos){
        case 0:
            infoMsg = "SMS option chosen";
            break;
        case 1:
            infoMsg = "WhatsApp option chosen";
            break;
        case 2:
            infoMsg = "Telegram option chosen";
            break;
        case 3:
            infoMsg = "Facebook Messenger option chosen";
            break;
    }

    createUserInfoMessage(infoMsg);
    saveChatChange(pos);
}
```

Comment: OK so this allows me to get into the Settings activity without crashing, but after I select a different option in the spinner, leave and return to the activity, the spinner is reset to the first array item. Also, onItemSelected fires without any user action.

Comment: @GroovinChip I updated my answer to address these concerns

Comment: Thanks so much for your help! I updated my code with your changes and now the spinner does update with the previously chosen selection. However, onItemSelected() still fires and shows me my Toast message.

Comment: @GroovinChip did you move the `setOnItemSelectedListener()` call to be after your `switch` that calls `chatPicker.setSelection()` ?

Comment: Yes, it looks like this: 
`chatPicker.setSelection(currentChat);
 chatPicker.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);`

Comment: @GroovinChip what happens if you move the `setOnItemSelectedListener()` call to your activity's `onResume()` method?

Comment: Doesn't change anything :/